# Suppose $CA=I_n$ (the $n \times n$ identity matrix. Show that the equation $A\textbf{x}=\textbf{0}$ has only the trivial solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $CA=I_n$ (the $n \times n$ identity matrix. Show that the equation $A\textbf{x}=\textbf{0}$ has only the trivial solution.

The textbook solution is as follows:

> If x satisfies $A\textbf{x} = \textbf{0}$, then $CA\textbf{x} = C\textbf{0} = \textbf{0}$ and so $I_n\textbf{x} = \textbf{0}$ and $\textbf{x} = \textbf{0}$. This shows that the equation $A\textbf{x} = \textbf{0}$ has no free variables. So every variable is a basic variable and every column of A is a pivot column.

Now I get that $I_n\textbf{x} = \textbf{0}$ would mean $\textbf{x}$ must be the trivial solution since there are no free variables and you have a pivot position at every column. However, I don't get how that implies that  $A\textbf{x}=\textbf{0}$ has the trivial solution since $A \neq I_n$. I don't quite get how $C$ comes into play for solving this problem.

Comment: If $A$ is not invertible, then $A$ cannot be full rank, thus having infinite solutions. I don't know if you know the equivalent formulation of invertiability though.

Comment: So this problem is supposed to be solved without invertibility since it hasn't been covered yet.

Comment: $I_nx=x$ by definition because $I_n$ is the identity matrix. Thus, $I_nx=0$ and $x=0$ is the same thing. No need to mention free variables or anything else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linear Algebra - Suppose $CA=I_n$. Show that the equation $Ax = 0$ has only the trivial solution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159746/linear-algebra-suppose-ca-i-n-show-that-the-equation-ax-0-has-only-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0} $$

$$ \Rightarrow CA\mathbf{x} = C\mathbf{0} $$

$$ \Rightarrow I_n\mathbf{x} = C\mathbf{0} $$

$$ \Rightarrow \mathbf{x} = C\mathbf{0} $$

$$ \Rightarrow \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0} $$

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence in the texbook solution is incomplete. What they have proved is $Ax=0$ implies $x=0$ so no vector other than $0$ is  a solution.

Comment: Sorry I had missed one of the solution sentences, I updated my question to include the missing sentence.